# How to get a sub-string after the last specified char ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, split, slice

lets say I have the following string :

```
var text = "A_B_C_190"
```

I want to be able to extract the number at the end (the last 3 chars after the last _ )

I tired :

```
text.substr(text.indexOf('_'), -1)
```

but that gave me null

Comment: [`lastIndexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp). Have you done any research?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use lastIndexOf method.

```js
var text = "A_B_C_190"
ans = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf('_')+1)
console.log(ans)
```

If you want to convert it to an integer, use `parseInt(ans)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.prototype.split` and `array.prototype.pop`:

```js
var text = "A_B_C_190";
console.log(text.split('_').pop());
```

Comment: This one is unnecessarily creating an array. It's better to use `lastIndexOf`